# Emit liquid from the whole of the mesh's faces?

Tags: physics

I would like to be able to emit liquid from the whole of my icosphere mesh.

As you can see, it only seems to appear from the bottom half.

[image: Liquid Emission]

Blender 3.6.5 / Windows 11

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MhhAzYOz5jRqyp5ewHIERhQKs6fmj7gM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi James, since you are not new here to BSE and because you didn't check any of your questions as "right answer" i just wanna let you know, that people help you here in their spare time for free. To help this site getting better and to be a good citizen you should click on the checkmark left to an answer, if the answer was helpful to you. thx. Then a green checkmark appears in the provided list of me - where you have no green checkmarks.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYsVF.png. And also it is a little sign that you are thankful.

Comment: regarding your question here: please provide blend file because you didn't show us any settings you made. thx.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, my bad. URL to file now attached.